# Using WordNet to find out whether two words are synonyms of each other

Tags: python, loops, wordnet, synset

I'm having troubles with the loop. I need it to print 'synonyms' just once if any of the lemmas of that sense match with word2, otherwise 'not synonyms', but only once.

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

word1 = 'motorcar'
word2 = 'automobile'

for syn in wn.synsets(word1):
    for lemma in syn.lemma_names():
        if lemma == word2 and lemma != word1:
            print('Synonyms')
        elif all(syn.lemma_names()) != word2:
            print('not synonyms')
```

Comment: Hi! I'm not sure of what you need... Did you already try putting `break` or `return` after `print('Synonyms')` ?

Comment: Also, can you post the output of your code? For me (using the 'popular' dataset) it outputs `not synonyms
not synonyms
Synonyms
not synonyms
not synonyms`

Answer (score 0):

The usual pattern is to initialize a variable outside the loop, then report the result at the end of the loop. Something like this:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

word1 = 'motorcar'
word2 = 'automobile'

for syn in wn.synsets(word1):
    is_synonym = False
    for lemma in syn.lemma_names():
        if lemma == word2 and lemma != word1:
            is_synonym = True
    print('Synonyms' if is_synonym else 'not synonyms')
```

Answer (score 0):

Same result but merging all the lemma lists in a single list named 'names' instead of using pivot boolean:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

word1 = 'motorcar'
word2 = 'automobile'

names = []
for syn in wn.synsets(word1):
    for lemma in syn.lemma_names():
        names.append(lemma)

print('Synonyms' if word2 in names else 'not synonyms')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of the Python package [WordHoard](https://pypi.org/project/wordhoard).  This package can be used to find semantic relationships between words including a word's antonyms, synonyms, hypernyms, hyponyms and homophones.

- [GitHub WordHoard](https://github.com/johnbumgarner/wordhoard)
- [WordHoard documentation](https://wordhoard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```
from wordhoard import Synonyms

word1 = 'motorcar'
word2 = 'automobile'

synonym_list = Synonyms(word1).find_synonyms()
find_word = [word for word in synonym_list if word == word2]

if find_word is not None:
    print(f'{word2} is a synonym of {word1}')
    # print output
    automobile is a synonym of motorcar.
else:
    print(f'{word2} is not a synonym of {word1}')
```

I have found *wordnet* to be very limited.  For instance these are the synonyms for *motorcar* from *wordnet*:

```
['auto', 'automobile', 'car', 'machine']
```

**WordHoard** is designed to query other sources.  For example the query below returns 152 synonyms for the word *motorcar*.

```
from wordhoard import Synonyms

synonym_list = Synonyms('motorcar').find_synonyms()
print(len(synonym_list))
152
```

If you decided to use **WordHoard** please let me know how it works for your use case.