# Python contextual similarity between strings

Tags: python, string

I want to find contextual similarity between strings in Python. I tried to use modules like fuzz.partial_ratio, SequenceMatcher, and Levenshtein.jaro_winkler. The problem is that those modules do not give me contextual solutions.
For example, the string "learn" and the string "earn" get a high score of 0.93, it is clear that those strings are not contextually similar...
Which module can help me here?

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like an NLP problem, not string processing.

Comment: "*The problem is that those modules do not give me contextual solutions.*" Have you read the documentation for each of those methods? If you had, it would be very clear that they do not provide anything that could be remotely considered "*contextual*".

Comment: "*Which module can help me here?*" Questions seeking library recommendations are explicitly off-topic for Stack Overflow. See the [help/on-topic] for more information.

Comment: `synsets` in nltk's wordnet may provide a path forward [like some of the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65167938/using-wordnet-to-find-out-whether-two-words-are-synonyms-of-each-other). Not having worked in this space, I'm not sure how reasonable it would be to iterate to find linkage (perhaps looking up 3 or 4 levels of deeps of synonyms to find the other word fed in, each level being a 'distance' from the starting word). That being said, I'm just guessing at what you mean by "Contextual".

Comment: After a little diggin, here's what I think you are after: https://docs.huihoo.com/nltk/0.9.5/api/nltk.wordnet.similarity-module.html  Example: `print(wordnet.lin_similarity(wordnet.synsets('car')[0], wordnet.synsets('jet')[0], wordnet_ic.ic('ic-brown.dat')))` Where `car` and `jet` return a lin_similarity of `.63`. And `learn'` and `earn` return `0`.